# Starting program using execv and passing arguments with out raising argc

Tags: c, arguments, fork, argc

Ive been given this code in class:

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        if(argc)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        puts(argv[3]);
        return 0;
    }
```

Now, Im supposed to write a second program which executes this and makes it print "Hello World!". So I have to find a way to pass in arguments (I assume with execv) while having argc stay at 0.

This is what I have so far:

```c
int main()
{
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if(pid == 0)
    {
        char *argv[] = { "filepath", "placeholder",
                            "placeholder", "Hello World!" };
        execv("filepath", argv);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(pid, 0, 0);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is going to run on Linux.

I tried mbj's original suggestion to pass a 0 in the arguments array, which sadly didnt work. However if I put 0 as the first argument, argc becomes 0, but then I get the output "LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8" when trying to print the arguments. Googling this didnt really help me either.

Im at a total loss here, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: On what operating system is this going to run?

Comment: On Linux, gonna add it to the post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I figured this out now, after some experimenting of my own.

Since passing an array that starts with `NULL` (`0`) to `execv` results in the program printing out `LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8`, I realized that it must means that `argv[3]` is referring to an element in the process *environment* (LC_MEASUREMENT is one of the environment variables used to configure locale settings in Linux).

#### Solution with `execv`

Since `execv` will copy the current environment to the new program, we just have to modify the environment and put the string `"Hello World!"` in the correct spot before calling `execv`. It turns out that the string which gets printed is the one pointed to by index 2 of the environment.

To access the current environment, we need to declare the `environ` variable outside of `main`:

```c
external char **environ;

int main() 
{
    ...
```

And then do this before calling `execv`:

```c
        char *argv[] = { NULL };
        environ[2] = "Hello world!";
        execv("filepath", argv);
```

#### Simpler solution with `execve`

Instead of declaring `external char **environ` and modifying the current environment before calling `execv`, we can use the `execve` function, which lets us pass in a new array of strings to use as the environment for the program:

```c
        char *argv[] = { NULL };
        char *envp[] = { "foo", "bar", "Hello World!", NULL };
        execve("filepath", argv, envp);
```

As the above code snippet shows, `"Hello World!"` needs to be at index `2` of the environment, regardless of which method we use.

#### How it works

The reason this works is that there's a standard for how command-line arguments and the environment are laid out in process memory when a program is executed: The environment array of char pointers is placed right after the command-line arguments array.

Since these arrays are terminated with a NULL entry, it will look like this:

```c
+---------+---------------------------------------+ 
| Args    | Environment                           |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|  NULL   | envp[0] | envp[1] | envp[2] |  NULL   | 
+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
    ^         ^                   ^                     
    |         |                   |
 argv[0]    argv[1]     ...     argv[3]
```

I hope the ASCII art helps you understand why `argv[3]` means the same thing as `environ[2]` when we execute the program like this.

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked!
Thanks for the great explanation as well, made it really easy to understand.